# save checked checkboxes when Page reloads

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, browser

For my search-engine I designed a filter using a form with checkboxes. When submitting those, the filter function works fine (using Flask for this). Yet the checkboxes which where used as a filter are unchecked again when the results are shown. Do I need to save the information in the localStorage, and how can this be done?
Thanks for your help <3

This is a part of my Code for the checkbox (I am a newbie to HTML/JS):

```html
 <form>                  
  <article class="card-group-item">                      
    <header class="card-header">                          
      <span class="title">Document Types </span>               
    </header>                     
      <div class="filter-content">
          <div class="card-body">
             <label class="form-check" >
                 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="doctype" value="offer" id="offer">
                 <span class="form-check-label">Offer</span>
             </label> <!-- form-check.// -->
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>
          </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
      </div>
   </article> <!-- card-group-item.// -->
 </form>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work for me. It only shows the checkbox status when when chlicking the Webpages return-button. But not when the page refreshes...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `checked` to it

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="doctype" value="offer" id="offer" checked>
```

Comment: this does unfortunatly not solve my Problem :(. I only want those checkboxes to be checked, which where selected for the filter. 
in detail: you select a checkbox, hit submit and the page reloads and shows the desired content, but the checkboxes, which created the content are not checked anymore

Comment: With your advise, all my checkboxes would be checked by default... thanks anyway

Comment: You say 
`Yet the checkboxes which where used as a filter are unchecked again when the results are shown. `
So the info for the boxes that have to be checked is kept somewhere? You can loop through the checkboxes `onload` and check if they have to be checked. If they have to be checked, add the checked property to the box.

Comment: could you show me a simple example for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **checked** in your checkbox and read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

```html
 <form>                  
  <article class="card-group-item">                      
    <header class="card-header">                          
      <span class="title">Document Types </span>               
    </header>                     
      <div class="filter-content">
          <div class="card-body">
             <label class="form-check" >
                 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="doctype" value="offer" id="offer" checked>
                 <span class="form-check-label">Offer</span>
             </label> <!-- form-check.// -->
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>
          </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
      </div>
   </article> <!-- card-group-item.// -->
 </form>
```

Comment: this does unfortunatly not solve my Problem. I only want those checkboxes to be checked, which where selected for the filter. With your advise, all my checkboxes would be checked by default...
thanks anyway