# Maintain colllapse-state after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

In my Sidebar I included a collapse button to show/hide a form. Now I want to maintain the collapse-state when refreshing the page:
If the form was un-collapsed before refreshing the page, it must stay like this after the refresh.

I think I need to use the localStrorage in JavaScript, but I actually don't know how to use this.

This is my HTML:

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
    <ul class="sidebar navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                      <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                      <span>Search Filter</span>
                  </a>
          </li>


 </ul>

<!-- Form -->
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
<form>
......
</form>
```

I found some code only but it seems like it does not work for me..:

```
var shown = []

// On collapse
shown.remove($(this).attr('id'));
localStorage.setItem('shown', shown);

// On open
shown.push($(this).attr('id'));
localStorage.setItem('shown', shown);

// On page load
var shown = localStorage.getItem('shown');
for (var s in shown) {
    $('#collapseExample' + s).show(); 
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Bootstrap 4 collapse example that works. The main difference from the starter template is that I moved the jQuery import to the top of the file so that I could use the document.load function. I've added comments to the code but if anything's still not clear, keep asking questions. Note that I left the vanilla javascript answer for historical comments and in case it helps you, too.

I used the starter page from here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

And the first collapse example from here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        // store a reference to the collapse div so that 
        // we don't have to keep looking it up in the dom
        const collapseExample = $("#collapseExample");

        // register a callback function to the collapse div that
        // will be called every time the collapse is opened.
        collapseExample.on("shown.bs.collapse", function() {
            // since we know that that this function is called on
            // open, we'll set the localStorage value to "show" 
            localStorage.setItem("collapseExample", "show");
        });

        // register a callback function to the collapse div that
        // will be called every time the collapse is closed.
        collapseExample.on("hidden.bs.collapse", function() {
            // since we know that that this function is called on
            // open, we'll set the localStorage value to "hide" 
            localStorage.setItem("collapseExample", "hide");
        });

        // Since this function runs on page load (meaning only once), we can
        // check the value of localStorage from here and then call the
        // bootstrap collapse methods ourselves:

        // Check the value of the localStorage item
        const showExampleCollapse = localStorage.getItem("collapseExample");

        // Manipulate the collapse based on the value of the localStorage item.
        // Note that the value is determined by lines 36 or 44. If you change those,
        // then make sure to check that the comparison on the next line is still valid.
        if (showExampleCollapse === "show") {
            collapseExample.collapse("show");
        } else {
            collapseExample.collapse("hide");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <p>
        <a
          class="btn btn-primary"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          href="#collapseExample"
          role="button"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapseExample"
        >
          Link with href
        </a>
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseExample"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapseExample"
        >
          Button with data-target
        </button>
      </p>
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
          terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
          labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

END BOOTSTRAP ANSWER

BEGIN VANILLA JAVASCRIPT ANSWER

Here's a basic, self-contained version of what you seem to be trying to do. It's not pretty, but hopefully, it's clear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
    function getCollapsed() {
        const state = localStorage.getItem('collapsed');
        if(state === 'collapsed'){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function getStatus(){
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
        const isCollapsed = getCollapsed();
        if(isCollapsed){
            resultDiv.innerHTML = "collapsed";
        }else{
            resultDiv.innerHTML = "un-collapsed";
        }
    }
    function toggleCollapse(){
        const isCollapsed = getCollapsed();
        if(isCollapsed){
            localStorage.setItem('collapsed', 'un-collapsed');
        }else{
            localStorage.setItem('collapsed', 'collapsed');
        }
        getStatus();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getStatus()">
    <div>
        <button onclick="toggleCollapse()">Toggle Collapse</button>
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since it looks like you're using bootstrap, I'll update this with a bootstrap collapse example in a few minutes.

Comment: thanks a lot! i included your code in mine, only adjusting the id from "result" to "collapseExample". The function onclick="toggleCollapse()" is know used when submitting the form. But it still does not work... do you have an idea what went wrong? thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @alipfi: I'm about to edit this answer with the default starter from bootstrap 4 and their first collapse component example.  This one should help more. I'm going to leave the first one at the bottom of the post, but they are actually 2 separate answers.

Comment: could you may be help with my 2nd issue? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876694/save-checked-checkboxes-when-page-reloads/58876742?noredirect=1#comment104022446_58876742
I am trying to save the checkboxstatus of my form when refreshing the Page. I have not found a proper solution yet... thanks in advance <3

Comment: I'm glad to take a look, but it sounds like the same thing might work, just with a different localStorage key?

Comment: @alipfi: Your other question was closed with a link to a localStorage solution that should work.

Comment: @alipfi: Make sure you take some time, when you get a chance to understand why it works. Then you'll be able to help someone else, too. <3